# Scala lambda style (x) => {...} vs { (x) => ... }

Tags: scala, lambda, coding-style

I'm new to Scala and am just reading some sample code using [ReScala](http://www.guidosalvaneschi.com/rescala/main/index.html). In that code, it appears the author uses two styles to define lambdas:

1. `{ x => println(x) }`
2. `(x => { println(x) })`

I assume these two styles are semantically equivalent. However I think the second style allows easy addition of additional statements in the lambda body.

Is that correct? Which way is more "idiomatic"? It would also be interesting whether `{}` opens a new lexical scope (like in C) or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume these two styles are semantically equivalent.

Yes

> However I think the second style allows easy addition of additional statements in the lambda body.

No. Or, rather, yes, but so does the first style.

> Which way is more "idiomatic"?

This is opinion-based. Opinions vary.

> It would also be interesting whether `{}` opens a new lexical scope (like in C) or not.

Yes they do.

Comment: To clarify, could I easily write `{ x => println(x) \n doSomethingElseWith(x)  }` to extend the first style lambda with additional statements?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.